# JStree : create jstree from smbclient directory structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jstree, directory-listing

I am using [sambal](https://github.com/johnae/sambal) gem for smbclient.
I want to create jstree from recursive directory listing from smbclient.

```
require "sambal"
client = Sambal::Client.new(domain:domain-name, host: host, share: 'all' ,user: 'abc', password: 'pswd')
client.cd("abc")
client.ask("recurse")
all_files_hash = client.ask("ls")
```

I have modified parse_files method of smbclient to have path in file listing hash.
Sample hash of direcory listing that I want to display in JStree:

```
    all_files_hash = {"."=>{:type=>:directory}, ".."=>{:type=>:directory}, 
    "log"=>{:type=>:directory, :path=>"\\abc"},
     "softwares"=>{:type=>:directory, :path=>"\\abc"}, 
    "test.txt"=>{:type=>:file, :path=>""},
 "test_data"=>{:type=>:directory, :path=>"\\abc"},
 ".keep"=>{:type=>:file, :path=>"\\abc\\log"},
 "alert.log"=>{:type=>:file, :path=>"\\abc\\log"}, 
"development.log"=>{:type=>:file, :path=>"\\abc\\log"},
 "test.log"=>{:type=>:file, :path=>"\\abc\\test_data"},
 "robomongo-0.8.4-x86_64.deb"=>{:type=>:file, :path=>"\\abc\\softwares"}, 
"sublime-text_build-3065_amd64.deb"=>{:type=>:file, :path=>"\\abc\\softwares"},
 "ubuntu"=>{:type=>:directory, :path=>"\\abc\\softwares"},
 "ubuntu.css"=>{:type=>:file, :path=>"\\abc\\softwares\\ubuntu"}}
```

How can I create jstree from recursive file listing that I have got in all_files_hash?

Expected Output :

```
 jstree_hash = [{"text" => "abc","path" => "\\abc","children" => [{"text" => "log","path"=>"\\abc\\log","children" => [{"text" => "development.log","path"=>"\\abc\\log\\developemnt.log"},{"text" => "alert.log","path"=>"\\abc\\log\\alert.log"}]}]}}]
```

I followed below links but no luck :
[nested hash](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/142330) and
[iterate over deep hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748475/iterate-over-an-deeply-nested-level-of-hashes-in-ruby)

Thanks in advance..

Comment: take a look at you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5523340/1380867 I think this is what you want